# Control rate of function calls per second

Tags: c++, c++11, time

An operation takes 65ms to complete. It needs to be triggered '***numOpr***' times at a *specific target operations per second*.

How do we control the operation to be trigged at a specific rate?

Below is a sample that I tried but it doesn't seem to care about target operations per second. It is always at ~15ops at all valid targetOps values.

Target Environment : gcc5.x, C++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
int main()
{
    float ops;
    
    //target number of operations
    const std::intmax_t targetOPS = 10;
    
    //number of operations
    const std::size_t numOpr = 20;
    
    std::chrono::duration<double, std::ratio<1, targetOPS>> timeBetweenOperation;
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock, decltype(timeBetweenOperation)> tp;

    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> started = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    //need to run some operation 10 times at specific intervals
    for(size_t i= 0; i<numOpr;i++){
        //Some operation taking 65ms 
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(65));
        
        //delay between each operation if required to reach targetOPS
        tp = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + timeBetweenOperation;
        std::this_thread::sleep_until(tp);
    }
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto dt_us = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds> (now - started).count ();
     if (dt_us > 0)
     {
       ops = numOpr * 1000000.0 / dt_us;
     }
     else
     {
       ops = 0.0;
     }
     
     std::cout<<"Operations per second: "<< ops <<std::endl;
     std::cout<<"Target operations per second: ~"<< targetOPS <<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Why create your own ratio?  Why not just use `std::chrono::milliseconds(1000/targetOPS)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem #1 is that you didn't initialize `timeBetweenOperation`, so it will be set to 0 ticks at your 1/N rate.  Thus, you are always adding 0.  You can fix that by initializing it:

```
    std::chrono::duration<double, std::ratio<1, targetOPS>> timeBetweenOperation(1);
```

Problem #2 is the way you are doing the `sleep_until`.  You are sleeping until `now` plus the interval, so you'll always get 65ms PLUS your 100ms gab, resulting in 6 ops per second.  If you want the operation N times per second, you'll need to grab `now` BEFORE you do the 65ms operation.

```
    for(size_t i= 0; i<numOpr;i++){        
        //Compute target endpoint
        tp = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + timeBetweenOperation;
        // Some operation taking 65ms 
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(65));
        std::this_thread::sleep_until(tp);
    }
```

Comment: Yes! my bad. Thank you very much.

Comment: For better accuracy just call `now` once prior to entering the loop.  You can initialize `tp` with `auto tp = steady_clock::now() + timeBetweenOperation;`.  Then after the `sleep_until` you can just `tp += timeBetweenOperation;`.